# How to delete Items on wx.listCtrl from another frame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am running in trouble with wxPython

I have this code

```
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Lapop - Αδειες Υπαλλήλων", size = (700,400))

    # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
    panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(680, 340),
                                 style=wx.LC_REPORT
                                       | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                                 )
    self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_COMMAND_LEFT_DCLICK, self.DoubleClick)
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'ID',width=40)
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Name', width=250)
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Row1', width=150)
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, 'Row2', width=150)

    sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)


    panel.SetSizer(sizer)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

def UpdateListView(self):
    self.list_ctrl.DeleteAllItems()
    print self.list_ctrl.GetItemCount()
```

And from another class (another wx.Frame), I try to update the list on MyForm frame.

```
MyForm().UpdateListView()
```

Although I get the count of items in list, but unfortunatelly, I can't delete the items.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Firstly, include pubsub

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
```

Then, I neet to set the subscribe, right after the creating of ListCtrl

```
self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(680, 340),
                                 style=wx.LC_REPORT
                                       | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                                 )
self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_COMMAND_LEFT_DCLICK, self.DoubleClick)
pub.subscribe(self.UpdateListView, 'UpdateListview')
```

also, I need to make the function inside same class of ListCtrl creation.

```
    def UpdateListView(self):
    self.list_ctrl.DeleteAllItems()
    #Do something else
```

Then, from any other class you just send a message to update the list.

```
pub.sendMessage('UpdateListview')
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyForm().UpdateListView()` will create a *new instance* of `MyForm`, not give you a reference to the existing one. To do that you just need to give your other frame a reference, or some way to access the reference to the existing `MyForm`.

Comment: Ok, but how to do this? Also, why I can get the "GetItemCount" working correclty?

Comment: The same way you access any object from another, there's nothing special about frames here.  Give one a reference to the other object, save it in `self`, and then when you need it you call a method of the other object, like `self.otherFrame.doSomething()`